How to preserve large database query results on the server for future processing
I have an ASP.NET Core Razor pages application that displays data in a Javascript chart. In some scenarios, this chart can have up to 1 300 000 datapoints / database rows. Depending on the selected date range in the chart, I want to make a request to the server to calculate stats like min, max, and average values for the selected time range.
The problem I'm running into is how best to fetch the data once the request reaches the server. Making a database query for 1 300 000 rows every time a new date range is selected isn't the best strategy. Some ideas I've come up with are to pass the data from the front-end in the request or cache the data on the server using a MemoryCache and fetch it during the request to avoid a database query. But I am unsure if storing 1 300 000 items in a MemoryCache is good practice or even doable.
In short, what is a time-efficient way to store 1 300 000 rows of data for future processing when requests are made from the front end?
Here is my MySQL database query using Dapper:
    public async Task<ICollection<ReadingModel>> GetAllAsync(int sensorId, int locationId, DateTime? afterDateMT = null, DateTime? beforeDateMT = null)
    {
        try
        {
            using IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("Default"));

            var query = new StringBuilder();
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

            query.AppendLine("""
                SELECT * FROM Reading R
                WHERE R.LocationId = @LocationId AND R.SensorId = @SensorId 
                """);

            parameters.Add("LocationId", locationId);
            parameters.Add("SensorId", sensorId);

            if (afterDateMT != null)
            {
                query.AppendLine("""
                    AND R.RecordedAtMT > @StartDateMT
                    """);
                parameters.Add("StartDateMT", afterDateMT.Value);
            }
            if (beforeDateMT != null)
            {
                query.AppendLine("""
                    AND R.RecordedAtMT < @EndDateMT
                    """);
                parameters.Add("EndDateMT", beforeDateMT.Value);
            }

            query.AppendLine("""
                ORDER BY R.RecordedAtMT ASC
                """);

            var result = await connection.QueryAsync<ReadingModel>(query.ToString(), parameters);

            return result.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error has occured while fetching ReadingModels with SensorId: {sensorId} and LocationId: {locationId} and StartDateMT: {afterDateMT}", sensorId, locationId, afterDateMT);
            throw;
        }
    }


The most efficient thing here would be to get the database server to do the grouping and aggregation, so that you don't need to fetch all the data - just the aggregates you need. However, 1.3M isn't necessarily either large or small - everything is relative (especially if the rows don't contain masses of text data, etc) - also it might matter whether this is an intranet application Vs an internet application (i.e. how much bandwidth can be assumed)

You should show your LINQ query so someone can suggest some optimizations.  SQL-Server should already be doing some caching for you.

@browsermator - I've updated the post to show the query, I am using MySQL not SQL Server.

You could try database sharding and data processing to increase the query speed. This will allow the database to be more available. What is similar is to implement the segmented caching, will improve the query speed.
